# Qtip2 ajax: cache vs once

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, qtip, qtip2

I am using a qtip2 jquery plugin.

To prevent caching of the ajax response, I can either use:

```
ajax: {
  once: false
}
```

or

```
ajax: {
  cache: false
}
```

Both seems to work identically.

What is the difference? Is one deprecated? Which is preferred / recommended?

I have googled and studied the qtip documentation but I can't find any help.

Answer (score 0):

`ajax` attribute of `content` property has been [deprecated as of version 2.1](http://qtip2.com/options#content.ajax). `Once` is a property of qTip's `ajax` whereas `cache` is property of jQuery's `$.ajax`. You should stick with `cache: false` in my opinion.